# How do I send a user an HTML file from S3 or Cloudfront using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to simply re-route the user to a page (say bucket.amazons3.com/hello.html) while still making it appear as if they are on DOMAIN.COM/hello.html ... I want to do this say if a certain IF condition passes..

eg:

```
if (RAILS == "cool") && (S3.exists?("hello.html"))
 send_to_s3
end
```

where "send_to_s3" simply redirects the user to Amazon Cloudfront or S3 and renders the "hello.html" page in their browser. But they feel like they never left my website..

Now imagine I want to do this same behavior with Hello1.html, Hello2.html, Hello3.html..... Hello20Million.html...

How can I do this efficiently without significantly increasing my server load?

How would I do this in RAILS running on server like Thin/Puma/Webrick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could go about doing this:

1. Using iframes in your view which point to the S3 URL.
2. Doing a server side request to the amazon URL and rendering the response as if it is one of your rails views.

The first option is quite simple. If your condition is satisfied you open one of your rails views which has an embedded iframe with its `src` attribute pointing to the S3 URL. You will have to take care of the iframe dimensions (width x height) dynamically in JS to give the user a seamless experience (window resize etc).

In the second option you can actually request for the S3 URL through ruby using `open-uri` and then render the response you get into your own view. To request for the file URL use the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'
url_response = open('http://example.com/file_to_read.htm').read
```

In your view you need to render the `url_response`:

```
<%= url_response.html_safe %>
```

Using `html_safe` you tell rails that you want to output the string as is without any encoding to make it html safe.

Using either of these options will make it *appear* as though the request is coming from your server.

P.S: I was also wondering that it is also possible to do this via URL rewriting or proxy pass using `.htaccess` or similar but in your question you have specifically asked about "Rails".

Comment: Hi Tanzeel, thanks for your detailed response... I have a few concerns however.. 1> will the iframe have ugly scrollbars inside scrollbars? 2> I love the architecture of doing an iframe from server load perspective (imagine i have 1 million requests per day) but the Usability and User-Experience are major concerns and I believe the ajax hack you mentioned is not realtime right? (i.e. there is lag?) your second solution seems better from a User-Experience perspective but may not be as good from a server-load perspective.... more on this below...

Comment: Solution 2> I like this very much but I am a bit cost-sensitive.. how many Heroku dynos do you estimate I might need to consume on something like Heroku .. each additional dyno costs roughly $15 per month. I am aiming at a steady traffic handling capacity of 1 million per day for instance.

Comment: I'm also curious about the URL rewriting or proxy pass approach but with Rack compliant servers like Puma or Unicorn or Thin.. Maybe I will start another question on StackOverflow for this one... but I need to be more descriptive (dont really know what URL rewriting or proxy passing is from a functional standpoint)

Comment: @sambehera From your comments I feel the iframe approach will be more cost-sensitive and load-sensitive (it will hit the amazon servers directly for the iframe content). As for the question on the scrollbars, if you do it _right_ you will _not_ get double scrollbars. Look around for answers related to resizing elements to fit window viewports/screen. Doing the iframes is more effort on the HTML and JS is a given to resize the frame.

Comment: Also the second solution means there is a requirement of having tons of memory to store HTML files inside ruby variables as I am anticipating 1 Million requests per day... which means a lot of requests per second! I'm afraid the second approach might not even be possible unless I have HUGE memory on my server?

Comment: @sambehera Rather than me trying to explain URL rewriting and proxy pass in the comments I think you can find some better answers on SO (or google them). ;)

Comment: @sambehera If your URL and HTML is going to be static you can _cache_ it in memory for all requests. But that has to be thought through (like when will the cache purge). As I said above the `iframe` is the easiest (though not the most beautiful) solution to the factors in your problem.

Comment: I am leaving this question open for a while despite the great iframe answer (technical hack) .. because I want to see if the geniuses on SO come up with something better.. otherwise I'll deffo accept your answer in a couple days :)

Comment: @sambehera I understand. Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: I found a less hacky way.. but Im accepting your answer since it also works! My way is to point a CNAME in my DNS server to Cloudfront.. It'll have a final name like static.domain.com ... it looks like it is my site but it is actually a cloudfront distribution. I will then set the CDN's origin to be S3 .. where all the millions of files will be stored.

Comment: @sambehera That is indeed a cleaner approach. Though many developers do _not_ have access or are _not_ allowed to modify the servers DNS records. Thanks for the accept.